# Is it Possible to make installer experience like photosuru in wix?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

hii,
As we can make installer using SCE(Syndicated Client Experiences) kit like photosuru

http://tozon.info/blog/post/2009/02/07/photoSuru-install-experience.aspx

what i want is that change images on the progress of installation as u can see in the photosuru.i want the same in wix. it makes a better installer experience possible in wix.

Is it possible to change images(Bitmaps) in wix at installation time??
i need help from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, seeing as how the photoSuru installer is written in WiX and you can download the source code from [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/starter-kits/sce/ScePhotoViewer.exe) it should be fairly easy :)

Comment: thanx sascha,.but it doesn't help me.i could not get how to do this.